# How to move multiple directories, but exclude files in current path with similar name?

Tags: linux, mv

Say I have a directory that contains the following:

```
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
...
dir50/
dir1.txt
dir2.txt
dir3.txt
...
dir50.txt
```

I have been using mv dir* /someotherpath/, then move the *.txt files back.  Is there a way to move only the directories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your directory structure is only 1 level deep `mv dir*/ destination` will accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `find` to accomplish this task

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "dir*"  -exec mv '{}' destination/ \;
```

Change `maxdepth` parameter or remove it if you directory structure has more levels

Answer (score 0):

With a file structure like this:

```
/dir2move2
/dir
  /subdir1
  /subdir2
  index.js
```

To move only the sub directories and not the files you could just do:

`mv ./dir/*/ ./dir2move2`